# ¿Proviene la palabra "repostar" de las antiguas postas de los correos?

Tags: etimología, verbos

Leyendo "Miguel Strogoff", de Julio Verne, aprendí el concepto de "posta" y "casa de postas", el lugar donde un correo podía dejar a su caballo fatigado por el viaje y montar en otro descansado y así poder continuar el viaje con la máxima premura.

El concepto es básicamente el mismo que el de entrar hoy día con un coche en una estación de servicio y *repostar*, pudiendo así continuar el viaje unos cuantos kilómetros más.

Por tanto, me parecía muy lógico que la palabra *[repostar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W3qQioL)* proviniera del concepto de *[posta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TojRrA5)*, palabra antigua ya recogida por Covarrubias. Sin embargo, para mi sorpresa la palabra "repostar" viene en el diccionario sin etimología. He visto que en el DLE solo aparece desde 1956, aunque en otros diccionarios del siglo XIX aparece simplemente como sinónimo de "pertrechar". Confirmo en el CORDE algunos (pocos) casos de "repostar" en ese siglo.

Así pues, ¿proviene la palabra "repostar" del concepto de "posta"?

Answer (score 2):

*Posta* y *repostar* provienen en último término de *posit-* (*posita, positus, positum*), el participio perfecto pasivo del verbo latino *pōnere*, aunque han llegado a nuestro castellano actual por diferentes vías. De la misma familia son *puesto* (en todos sus sentidos), *repuesto*, *repostero*, *repositorio* y *depósito* (estas últimas dos palabras son cultismos, como se evidencia por la presencia de la *-i-* en *-posit-*, eliminada regularmente por síncopa en todas las otras).

Una posta o un puesto (it. *posto*) es literalmente un lugar donde se ha puesto o colocado algo. Puede tratarse de un puesto militar, es decir, un lugar donde se ha construido un fuerte o donde se ha destinado una guarnición, en cuyo caso deberá contar con lugar para descansar, con provisiones, municiones, etc. En este sentido nótese cómo se utiliza el término *base* para esta misma idea (literalmente: el soporte o cimiento de una guarnición militar), y cómo en inglés *to be stationed* significar "estar destacada una tropa en cierto lugar".

Del sentido militar estricto se pasa al más genérico de *posta* como lugar donde un viajero puede parar para descansar y/o para aprovisionarse o cambiar de caballos. Además de los ejércitos en movimiento, los viajeros más frecuentes serían personas que llevaban mensajes, fueran oficiales o privados; de ahí que la idea de *posta* terminase también unida al concepto de correo. A pesar de que en castellano hemos perdido esa raíz, "correo" sigue siendo *posta* o una palabra similar en muchísimas lenguas occidentales, y por supuesto en castellano mantenemos el adjetivo *postal*.

La posta como lugar para que un viajero cambie de caballos y continúe su camino no es incompatible con la posta como base para un sistema de correo por relevos, donde distintos mensajeros se turnan para llevar el mensaje hasta el siguiente lugar. En cualquiera de los dos casos se requiere un *repositorio* o *depósito*, es decir, un conjunto de bienes y servicios preparados y listos para ser entregados a quien los requiera al pasar, para sustituir (reponer) los que consumió en el viaje.

En el Diccionario de Autoridades se citan muchas definiciones de *posta*, que incluyen el lugar en sí, los caballos que en él se guardan, la distancia entre una posta y otra, etc. Como el concepto es amplio se presta para esta clase de derivaciones metonímicas y figurativas.

Evidentemente *repostar* con el significado de "pertrechar un barco" es una nueva derivación figurativa. En efecto las postas del barco son los puertos en los que toca, y lo repuesto son sus provisiones y otros insumos necesarios.

Answer (score 1):

No he encontrado en ningun sitio la etimología específica, pero la definición del DLE de [**repostar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W3qQioL) es:

> 1. tr. **Reponer** provisiones, pertrechos, combustibles, etc. U. t. c. prnl. *El acorazado fondeó para repostarse.*

Por otro lado, de [**repostero**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W3urVhz), que parece cercano a **repostar**, si se indica la etimología:

> Del lat. **repositorius** *'que sirve para **reponer** y guardar'*.

Finalmente, [**posta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TojRrA5) tiene una etimología totalmente diferente:

> Del it. *posta*.

y el significado al que se hace referencia es

> 6. f. Conjunto de caballerías que se apostaban en los caminos cada dos o tres leguas, para que los tiros, los correos, etc., pudiesen ser relevados.

además de la diferencia etimológica muestra una diferencia conceptual: en la *posta* lo que había eran caballos para sustituir a los de los viajeros y que pudieran seguir rápidamente su camino, sin esperar a que descansaran, no un sitio para que los caballos o viajeros repusieran provisiones ...

Todo esto me hace suponer que el origen de repostar es del latin *repositorius* o algo similar, no de posta.

**ADENDA**
En los primeros diccionarios en los que aparece **repostar** relaciónan la palabra con pertrechar **barcos** (incluido el ejemplo incluido en el DLE actual), lo que en mi opinión aleja aún más los conceptos de **posta** y **repostar**.

**ADENDA 2**
El DLE de 1970 y el de 1984 si indican una etimología para repostar: de **repuesto**.